# change args depending on select arg options in storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon

How can I show object depending on select argTypes?
I want show object data about selected options.

```
// dummy object

const dummyData = [
   { name : 'Primary'
     id   : 0  
   },
   { name : 'Secondary'
     id   : 1  
   },
]
```

```
argTypes: {
    colorType: {
      options: {'Primary' : 0, 'Secondary' : 1 },
      control: { type: 'radio' },
    },
    data: {
      table: dummyData[colorType] , // it's not real but I want show selected dummy Data
    },
```

I try `useArgs` add on in storybook docs,
and  [Conditional Controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#conditional-controls)
but I can't...